# Open particular note in enhanced note editor in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-experience

I am looking for a way to open a note linked to a record in enhanced note editor on a button click (see attached). Has anyone come across a similar requirement? Is there a way to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay, after some snooping, I think I figured out something.

just a **WARNING**, this is undocumented and so utilizing this doesn't guarantee that this will continue to work.

I found that there's an undocumented event called **`"notes:editNote"`** which expects 4 parameters (at least based on the code, it used `getParam()` to get these four keywords: **`noteId, reEnableEditNote, contextList`** and **`openInObjectHome`**). 
Based on my testing, the **`noteId`** is obvious to be the Note's record id. The purpose and behavior of **`reEnableEditNote`** (a boolean), **`contextList`** and **`openInObjectHome`** are still unknown.

Here's my helper.js function that invokes it:

```
editNote : function(noteId) {
    var editEvent = $A.get("e.notes:editNote");
    editEvent.setParams({
        "noteId": noteId
    });
    editEvent.fire();
}
```

Everything below can be ignored, but, if you want to know how I figured this out, read on.

**The Snooping**

Using Google Chrome's devtool, in 'Sources' tab, you would see the list of files the whole page utilizes. Under "top/_your_site_url_/components/notes" folder, you would see a file called "editPanelManager.js". That's the file where this event is defined.

Note: The file is minified. Beautify it first to get a better look :)

**Excerpts from the file:**

```
        }, {
            "ed": {
                "descriptor": "markup://notes:editNote"
            },
            "x": {
                "exprType": "PROPERTY",
                "byValue": false,
                "path": "c.editNote"
            }
```

From the "helper" block, where you would see the function itself (note: there's another one in the controller block that calls this one)

```
                editNote: function(b, c) {
                    var a = this,
                        e = c.getParam("noteId");
                    if (c.getParam("reEnableEditNote")) b.set("v.editNoteEnabled", !0);
                    else {
                        var d = c.getParam("openInObjectHome");
                        !$A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(e) && 0 === e.length && (e = null);
                        if ($A.get("$Browser.isDesktop") && d) $A.getEvt("markup://force:selectSObject").setParams({
                            recordId: e
                        }).fire();
                        else {
                            var h = {
                                    eventDef: e ? "noteRowClick" : "newNote",
                                    recordId: e
                                },
                                g =
                                c.getParam("contextList");
                            $A.get("$Browser.isDesktop") && ($A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(e) && $A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(g)) && (g = [{
                                id: $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id")
                            }]);
                            var d = b.get("v.editNoteEnabled"),
                                f = b.get("v.editPanel");
```

There ya go. Hope this helps.

Comment: I finally got around to trying this out. It seems to work. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Just wanted to add something for the next person encountering this...

If you want to populate the related record by default, pass this parameter:
```
let editEvent = $A.get("e.notes:editNote");
let params = {
  noteId: noteId, // don't save this if new note
  contextList: {id: parentId} // parent id is the default ContentDocumentLink
};
editEvent.setParams(params);
editEvent.fire();
```

Comment: Another piece for whoever encounters this next... if you have a parent component A, dragged onto a lightning page, and A has a child component B, B cannot use $A.get("e.notes:editNote"); directly (it will return undefined). I used the answer here (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217472/how-to-call-parent-lightning-components-method-in-child-component) to have component A get the Event and return it, then called that function from B. Once you have the event, then use the rest of this answer.